# Generics memory allocation in C#

Tags: c#, memory, c#-4.0, memory-management, allocation

It is possible to centralize your memory allocation in C# by using a method like:

```
    public static void AllocateMemory<T>(out T allocatedObject)
    {
        try
        {
            allocatedObject = new T;
        }
        catch (System.OutOfMemoryException e)
        {
            allocatedObject = null;

            SignalFailureOfMemoryAllocation("Generic memory error " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

However, the line

```
 allocatedObject = new T;
```

does not compile. The method is intended only for classes (by reference) as allocatedObject's and should technically be possible. It works well e.g. when using "out T[]" as parameter to allocate generic arrays. Is there a syntax that would work?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Need to constrain T to be an object?

Comment: Add `where T: class, new()` after method arguments and create like `new T()`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? There's no benefit to this method. There *are* specific classes for buffer pooling though. In current .NET versions (4.0 is no longer unsupported) you can use the [System.Buffers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Buffers/) package and ArrayPool

Comment: *It works well e.g. when using "out T[]" as parameter to allocate generic arrays* Bear in mind that you are allocating space for the 32/64 bit references that the array contains, not space for the `T` instances it will actually be referencing. Its not altogether clear if you are aware of this distinction in light of your present question where you seem to want to allocate the `T` instance itself.

Comment: Finally, the [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory) package offers Span<T> which allows you to work with strings, arrays, unmanaged buffers with the same API. If you are looking for a way to reuse memory, this is the way forward. Check [Adam Sitnik's](http://adamsitnik.com/Span/) article

Comment: BTW an OutOfMemoryException usually means the memory is so fragmented that the runtime can't allocate a new chunk of memory. Typically caused if you add elements to a list one at a time, resulting in continuous reallocations and copying of the internal buffer. Is that the case perhaps? If so, use the `capacity` parameter in your list's constructor and set it to the number of objects you intend to add, or a high enough value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Three problems

First, you forgot the parentheses.

```
allocatedObject = new T;
```

Should be

```
allocatedObject = new T();
```

Second, need the [`new()` generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint):

```
public static void AllocateMemory<T>(out T allocatedObject)
```

Should be

```
public static void AllocateMemory<T>(out T allocatedObject) where T: new()
```

Third-- this only works for public parameterless constructors! No way around that really. If you have objects that require parameters for construction, or objects that are allocated via static methods and private constructors, you are S.O.L.

### A different approach

Maybe try passing a `Func<T>` instead. A lot more powerful.

```
public static T AllocateMemory<T>(Func<T> func) 
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch (System.OutOfMemoryException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic memory error " + e.ToString());
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var o = AllocateMemory(() => new MyClass());  //Default constructor
```

Or

```
var o = AllocateMemory(() => new MyClass(arg1, arg2));  //Constructor with parameters
```

Or

```
var o = AllocateMemory(() => SomeFactory.Instantiate<MyClass>()); //Using a factory class
```

Or even (if you use an [IoC container](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)):

```
container.RegisterType<MyClass>
  (
    c => AllocateMemory(() => new MyClass())  //Register for IoC
  );
```

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/khHNvE)